# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCenter' of undefined in map 5

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
// this function search location and show on map

function showAddressTextBox(address) { //    showAddressTextBox function search location and show on map 
    //    alert(address);
    var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); //this infowindows
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow2.setContent('<div><strong>Address:' + results[0].formatted_address + '</strong><br>' +
                    'Place ID: ' + results[0].place_id + '</div>');
                infowindow2.open(map, marker);
            });
            //            path = address;
            //            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            //            lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        } else {
            //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
} //end function
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, your `map` variable is undefined!

Are you not showing your entire code?  Where is the `map` variable defined?

The example shows that you have to define the `map` variable and initialize an actual map.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  }
```

See more here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: var map;      function initialize() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.15, 79.04);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                        myOptions);
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);  this in my code but map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);  this line errror only

Comment: You should update your question rather than pasting code into a comment, it's really hard to read.

Comment: Also, consider creating a jsfiddle.

Comment: Are you using jQuery at all?  If not, are you making sure you're putting this code *below* the map div physically in the code?  Is there a div with id="map"?  You need to show your HTML as well.